# How to efficiently combine one link calling on two methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

A User can have multiple Organizations. In a `session` hash it is defined for which organization a user currently is logged in for (which can only be 1 organization). There's also a view that displays an overview with a table of organizations the user is part of. On this screen the user can switch to another organization, which resets the `session` hash to that organization. Simplified version (removed validations):

```
def set_session(organization)
  session[:logged_in_for] = organization.id
end

def logged_in_organization
  set_session(user.organizations.first) if session[:logged_in_for].nil?
  @organization = Organization.find(session[:logged_in_for])
end
```

The overview screen also needs to contain other functions for each of the organizations (these functions are also available from other screens such as the profile of each organization, so their methods are already in place). An example could be the function to add a new user for the organization.

But these other function use `logged_in_organization` as the organization for which they perform the function (there are security reasons why I want to keep it that way).

Therefore, what I would like is that if the function in the overview screen is clicked it executes the `set_session(organization)` method before it executes the function:

1. executes `set_session(organization)` for that organization
2. executes for example `add_user_path`

Is this possible? I though about adding additional routes and methods. These would then first calls on `set_session(organization)` and after that on the function itself. But that would require quite a few additional routes and methods, and perhaps there's an easier way? (perhaps tell the `link_to` in the view to execute two methods?, although the link_to documentation does not seem to facilitate such)

---

**Update:** Would it be possible to add the second route as a param in the overview page; for example (other functions will have other syntax than `organization_id: organization.id` so that's not generic):

```
<%= link_to "Add user", move_on_path( organization, adduser_path(organization_id: organization.id) ) %>
```

With as move_on method:

```
def move_on(organization, url)
  set_session(organization)
  redirect_to url
end
```

**Clicking the link currently produces an error pointing to `def move_on(organization, url)`:  `wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)`. What am I doing wrong here?** P.S. I have the following route:

```
get 'move_on' => 'user#move_on', as: 'move_on'
```

Comment: Is it not possible that you send the user first to the `set_session` route and then redirect to the action the user was performing?

You can also pass params to the `link_to` function so it could be that you pass the first param as `set_session` function name and execute it and then the second parameter could be the function name you wish to execute afterwards.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. One problem would be that `logged_in_organization` also calls on `set_session` (added this to the OP) and then adding a `redirect` to `set_session` would make `logged_in_organization` not function correctly anymore.

Comment: Look at my above comment, I have edited it.

Comment: `there are security reasons why I want to keep it that way` - what reasons, exactly?

Comment: @EugZol, well what I've done throughout my app is that all functions are performed for the user's `logged_in_organization`, so the user does not set a value for organization each time it performs a function. I could of course change this, but don't really want to since its all throughout my app.

Comment: @Noman, I've implemented something that I think looks like what you suggest and added it to the OP (see update). Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the simplest way to handle that is just to modify your `logged_in_organization` method:

```
def logged_in_organization
  @organization ||= begin
    set_session(user.organizations.first) if session[:logged_in_for].nil?
    @organization = Organization.find(session[:logged_in_for])
  end
end
```

That way it won't overwrite `@organization` if it's already set. And then you just set it in `before_action` of relevant controllers, like so:

```
before_action :set_organization
def set_organization
  @organization = current_user.organizations.find(params[:organization_id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks @EugZol, instead of a `before_action`, do you also have an idea how I could get the idea to work that I describe in the update of the post?

Comment: @Nick You need to pass the values as parameters `move_on_path(organization: organization, url: adduser_path(organization_id: organization.id) )`, then in your controller the action doesn't receive any arguments `def move_on`, but you have access to `params[:organization]` and `params[:url]`.

Comment: @MurifoX's suggestion is correct, and you'd better ask another question for it, as it is separate issue. It's a good idea to look through [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) guide before that.